# How to set and get cookies

Tags: javascript

I want to simply set a cookie to chrome and get it back but the code returns undefined unexpectedly. What I'm missing?

```js
function setCookie(name,value) {
  document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
}

function getCookie(name) {
  let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

setCookie('user','john')

let cookie = getCookie('user');

console.log(cookie);
```

I'm working locally does it matter?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working locally does it matter?!

That depends on what you mean by "locally." If you're directly opening HTML files in your browser (so the address bar starts with `file:`), yes, it matters, because cookies are an HTTP thing.

To do web development locally, be sure to use a web server, because many things don't work or work *slightly* differently with `file:` URLs instead of `http:`/`https:` URLs. Many IDEs have an integrated web server for testing, or it's easy to install a basic version of Apache or nginx, etc.